# Ignoring VM_ERASEBKGND from paint event does not work every time on winform off-screen why?

Tags: c#, winforms, paint

I have a windows form application that draws image and geometry form in front of it.  I have a problem that occurs when I drag the windows form off-screen and bring it back on-screen, makes the part that went off-screen all cleared.

I read that this might occurs because of windows message sending to my application the **VM_ERASEBKGND** and clear the part that went off-screen. (Am I right ? )

So first, I have created a test application that only displays an image and I overrides the **WndProc** method that does work in that case, here how it is implemented :

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
  {
     switch (m.Msg)
     {
         //0x0014 reprensts VM_ERASEBKGND message
        case 0x0014:
           //ignore this message else pass it to base
           break;
        default:
           base.WndProc(ref m);
           break;
     }
  }
```

Basically, I'm am just ignoring **VM_ERASEBKGND** message, and it does work in that case. **The application is a Form that contains a PictureBox.**

Now, I wanted to integrate this to another project that is quite the same, a **PictureBox into a Form, but has some more Control such has ScrollBar , Axis, GridPanel.**

When overwriting the WndProc method the same way I did in another project, it doesn't work even though it goes into the break point and does not process **base.WndProc(ref m)**. However, it seems to doesn't care that I am not processing the message, it still does clear my Form.

**My question is** : is it possible that other control like axis and scrollbar makes the form cleared when moving off-screen even though I've overwritten WndProc like in the example above and ignored ERASEBKGND.

This is a really weird behavior from windows since it does work in one application, but not in another which is almost the same.

Comment: Is this win xp or vista and higher? For xp your logic works. In vista and higher no. Even if you ignore `WM_ERASEBKGND` the form **will** draw the background. The `WM_PAINT` message isn't called many times. Even if you move another window in front the form is not redrawn.

Comment: I am using Windows 7, do You know how I could tell my PictureBox not to clear itself when I am going off-screen while dragging it ?

Comment: When `WM_PAINT` is being called you have two options: Either you override it and draw your self or you let the system. Either way some kind of drawing will occur. Your drawings will be erased because the system does **NOT** have any knowledge of them. Telling the system to not draw anything doesn't solve your problem. When you move your window off screen and then on screen there is a portion that **NEEDS** to be drawn.

Comment: As I said the system does **NOT** have any knowledge what to draw so it fills it with some color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My easy trick to resolve this problem, which is not the best solutions in your case, but still works, is to override WndProc of your form and catch your VM_ERASEBKG. And instead of passing to base, Present back your swapchain which redraws your swapchain.

GPU and CPU from windows 32 handles often gives bad behavior when using DirectX with winforms.

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
      Select Case m.Msg
         Case VM_ERASEBKGND
            swapchain.Present(1,PresentFlags.None)
            Exit Select
         Case Else
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
            Exit Select
      End Select
   End Sub
```